# Can you undo changes to your visual selection?

Tags: vim

Say you're selecting a large region of text using `a` & `i`, but you make a mistake and accidentally select too much (say you accidentally type `at` and select the entire tag you are working in, losing your selections inside the tag).

Is there any way to undo a change in visual selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extent of the selection is stored in the `'<,'>` marks when you leave or operate on the selection.

Therefore, to "save" the selection, you'd have to leave and re-enter the selection: `<Esc>gv`. Then, if you accidentally select something undesired, you could restore the previous selection (within visual mode!) with ```>o`<``.